# Getting all Revisions with SVNKit

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am currently trying to get all SVN Revisions and afterwards check them out one after another and do something with them.

With

```
svn checkout http://hamcrest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ hamcrest-read-only
```

(using SVN 1.8.8) I get the code (I am just using hamcrest as an example).

After getting it, I am trying to do the following:

```
    FSRepositoryFactory.setup();
    SVNURL localRepo = FSRepositoryFactory.createLocalRepository(f, true,
            true);
    System.out.println("Repo: " + localRepo);
    SVNRepository repo = FSRepositoryFactory.create(localRepo);

    log.info("Revisions: " + repo.getLatestRevision() + " Path: "
            + f.getAbsolutePath());
    List<SVNLogEntry> col = (List<SVNLogEntry>) repo.log(
            new String[] { "" }, null, 0, repo.getLatestRevision(), true,
            true);

    for (Object o : col) {
        System.out.println("O: " + o + " " + o.getClass());
    }

    System.out.println("Col: " + col.getClass());
```

This unfortunately creates an empty repository, and deletes everything in it. This corresponds to the documentation of FSRepositoryFactory.create.

So I searched for an way to open an existing repository another way, and found `SVNURL localRepo = SVNURL.fromFile(f);`. Unfortunately, this produces the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/reichelt/workspace/hamcrest/hamcrest-read-only'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/reichelt/workspace/hamcrest/hamcrest-read-only'
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepository(FSRepository.java:796)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.getLatestRevision(FSRepository.java:121)
at de.performanzanalysator.vcs.SVNUtils.getVersions(SVNUtils.java:70)
at de.performanzanalysator.vcs.SVNUtils.main(SVNUtils.java:90)
```

Does anyone know weather there is a way to open an existing, already downloaded repository with SVNKit? The `SVNWCClient` seems right, but I can't find any method to open a repository with `SVNWCClient`.

I am using SVNKit 1.8.5.

Comment: Are you sure that `file:///home/..` is a valid path to the valid repo?

Comment: Yes, if I do cd /home/.. (normaly it's a longer path, without '..'), I get to a directory where I can do for example svn log, so it seems like it is a valid repo.

Comment: `/home/..` is the same as root folder `/`, while your checkout command designates `hamcrest-read-only` as the checkout target. You should recheck the location where you checked out the repo and pass the correct location into Java code. And, if you really managed to checkout into `/` on *nix system, you will have all kinds of problems.

Comment: The real path is `/home/reichelt/workspace/hamcrest/hamcrest-read-only`, which is a correct path and contains a .svn file. I only wanted to shorten the thread for readability and therefore wrote `/home/..`, but that is not the real path. Sorry, I should have written `/home/XX` or the real path in the beginning.

Comment: What is the version of SVNKit and what is the version of the svn client used to checkout the repo?

Comment: SVN Version is 1.8.8, SVNKit Version is 1.8.5 (downloaded from the repository http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52576/discussion-between-oleg-estekhin-and-david-reichelt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception mentioned in the questions happens because the `SVNRepository` class expects to be used against a repository but it is used against a working copy.

The server-side part of the SVN is called repository and the client-side part is called working copy. The `svn checkout` command is used the create a (usually local) working copy from a (usually remote) repository. The working copy contains a single revision only, and because of that some operations (log, for example) will need access to the remote repository.

The `SvnOperationFactory` class provides an API to perform all "generic" SVN tasks both against working copies and repositories. It can be used to get the full change log but remember that it will contact the repository even if the log operation is initiated against the local working copy.

```
File workingCopyLocation = new File( ... );

SvnOperationFactory operationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
SvnLog logOperation = operationFactory.createLog();
logOperation.setSingleTarget(
        SvnTarget.fromFile( workingCopyLocation )
);
logOperation.setRevisionRanges( Collections.singleton(
        SvnRevisionRange.create(
                SVNRevision.create( 1 ),
                SVNRevision.HEAD
        )
) );
Collection<SVNLogEntry> logEntries = logOperation.run( null );
System.out.println( "logEntries = " + logEntries );
```

You can use the same code to obtain the change log directly from the repository without checking out the working copy by changing the `setSingleTarget` initialization to point to the remote repository:

```
String repoLocation = "http://hamcrest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk";
logOperation.setSingleTarget(
        SvnTarget.fromURL(
                SVNURL.parseURIEncoded( repoLocation )
        )
);
```

Since SVNKit 1.7 the `SvnOperationFactory` is the preferred way of using SVNKit. The SVNKit still contains `SVNClientManager` which provides similar capabilities but it is considered obsolete.

The `SVNRepository` class and its subclasses are intended to interact with repositories, which is useful if you are writing software that creates, configures or serves SVN repositories. For example, you can use that API to get the change log directly from the repository but unless you are writing some server-side software that performs other repository-related tasks you should use `SvnOperationFactory` approach.

```
String repoLocation = "http://hamcrest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk";

// DAV allows access via http and https protocols
// use FSRepositoryFactory to access local repositories
// use SVNRepositoryFactory to access remote repositories via svn protocol
DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();
SVNRepository repository = DAVRepositoryFactory.create(
        SVNURL.parseURIEncoded( repoLocation )
);

repository.log(
        new String[]{ },
        0, -1,
        false, false,
        new ISVNLogEntryHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleLogEntry( SVNLogEntry logEntry )
            {
                System.out.println( "logEntry = " + logEntry );
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I realy missunderstanding of the concept working copy and repository, because in git this terms are used slightly different...